# How can I allow the turtle to check and move the patches in the front 3 places?

Tags: netlogo

I want to explore only the front three patches and make them move there.

It is based on the direction the turtle looks at as shown in the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtwCS.png)

Comment: There is no code in this question, which help to identify whats the language of use neither any of the code that is been tried

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `patch-ahead`, `patch-left-and-ahead` and `patch-right-and-ahead`